# How can I remove the white space (with an ");") above my header after minifying my website?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, minify, cloudflare

I have a problem with my website after minifying with W3 Cache Plugin and Cloudflare. I made the setup like it is told in this tutorial: https://onlinemediamasters.com/w3-total-cache-settings/

Now the website shows a white space above my header and ");" at the top left of the page, also in the white space there. Furthermore, the favicon doesn't show up anymore.

I deactivated both tools, but it didn't solve the problem, so I activated both again and it also didn't change anything. I also tried to deactivate the preloader and the minifying options of the theme itself, but it also didn't solve the problem.

You can check the website on: https://pazu.ch

Comment: looks like you have PHP code thats missing a ?> after it.

Comment: Do you know where?

Comment: @Amir you didn't provide any code so it would be impossible for us to know where the issue is

Comment: Looks like your `Google Analytics` JS is cut up `</script>);
</script>`

Comment: The stray characters are on line 113 of the source code in your site @Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section related to your google code is faulty. Try reinstalling it or disable and then enabling it again.
Look a the bottom of this code from your site header for the faulty code:

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-129372800-1" type="83a2a3a6616a36c5d2485580-text/javascript"></script>
<script type="83a2a3a6616a36c5d2485580-text/javascript">
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', 'UA-129372800-1', <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-129372800-1"></script>
<script type="83a2a3a6616a36c5d2485580-text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-129372800-1');
</script>);
</script>
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Those ");" characters are there directly after the opending `body` tag - look into the HTML code to see if it's there. If yes, delete it.